# ClearCase: How to get when a LABEL was created?

Tags: clearcase

I would like to get the date when a label was created.

The command below does list the labels, but all of them. I would like to only get the date associated with a specific label.

```
cleartool lstype -kind lbtype -invob $(cygpath -wa $VIEWDIR)
```

And if possible without extensive use of `grep` or `sed` to extract the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given lbtype, you can use the [`cleartool describe`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) command:

```
cleartool descr lbtype:MYLABEL@/vob/myvob
```

Combined with [`fmt_ccase`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), you can limit to only the date

```
cleartool descr  -fmt "%d" lbtype:MYLABEL@/vob/myvob
```

This gives the creation date of the label *type* (not when a label was set to a version)

Answer (score -2):

cleartool desc -fmt %d *LABEL@\VOB*